# PL SQL select count(*) giving wrong answer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have I table consisting of 3 columns: system, module and block. Table is filled in a procedure which  accepts system, module and block and then it checks if the trio is in the table:

```
select count(*) into any_rows_found from logs_table llt
where system=llt.system and module=llt.module and block=llt.block;
```

If the table already has a row containing those three values, then don't write them into the table and if it doesn't have them, write them in. The problem is, if the table has values 'system=a module=b block=c' and I query for values 'does the table have system=a module=d block=e' it returns yes, or, to be precise, any_rows_found=1. Value 1 is only not presented when I send a trio that doesn't have one of it's values in the table, for example: 'system=g module=h and block=i'. What is the problem in my query?

Comment: How is the question related to PL/SQL, packages or PL/SQL Developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in this:

```
where system = llt.system
```

Both `system`s are the same, it is as if you put `where 1 = 1`, so Oracle is kind of *confused* (thanks to you).

What to do? Rename procedure's parameters to e.g. `par_system` so that query becomes

```
where llt.system = par_system
```

---

Another option (worse, in my opinion) is to precede parameter's name with the procedure name. If procedure's name was e.g. `p_test`, then you'd have

```
where llt.system = p_test.system
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09):

> If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name takes precedence.

So when you do

```
where system=llt.system
```

that is interpreted as

```
where llt.system=llt.system
```

which is always true (unless it's null). It is common to prefix parameters and local variables (e.g. with `p_` or `l_`) to avoid confusion.

So as @Littlefoot said, either change the procedure definition to make the parameter names different to the column names, or qualify the parameter names with the procedure name - which some people prefer but I find more cumbersome, and it's easier to forget and accidentally use the wrong reference.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is alias used for table name.

```
where system=llt.system and module=llt.module and block=llt.block;
```

Table name alias in select query and input to procedure having the same name(i.e. llt
). You should consider either renaming one of them.